# Can TSizeGrip be used to move and resize components at runtime (within FireMonkey)?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

FireMonkey's predecessor advertised that it could be used to create CAD and GIS programs.  I've been exploring FireMonkey and thinking about how to create a simple CAD program.  A basic function is to move shapes around on the screen using the mouse.  FireMonkey includes a TSizeGrip component, which I suspect may be applicable to moving shapes and providing nodes at corners and edges of a shape for a user to click on.  However, the documentation for TSizeGrip hasn't been completed.

Can TSizeGrip be used to allow end-user movement of FireMonkey shapes?  If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

**TSizeGrip** is provided specifically to act as a "grab handle" for resizing a **form**, not arbitrary FireMonkey controls or containers.

You can see this quite easily by creating a new FireMonkey HD application.  Drop a **TPanel** on the form and then drop a **TSizeGrip** onto that panel.

Run the application and you will find that when you mouse over and click on the size grip and drag, the form is resized, not the panel.  A size grip control would normally be anchored to the lower right of a form.

If you are wondering why you need a control with such apparently limited use when resizable forms can just be resized using their border, the answer is that it can sometimes be useful to have a form be resizable without having the full draggable border style.  e.g. modal dialog boxes.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of what TSizeGrip is for.

Answer (score 0):

No - with one exception.

If you create a new component in which you use *TPanel* and *TSizeGrip* – *TSizeGrip* will control *TPanel*'s size, not *TForm*'s size.